# Looking for a certain probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, distribution-tails

I would like to know if one can find a probability distribution with finite mean and the following property: $F(2^{i+1})-F(2^i)\le p$ for given parameter $0<p<1$ all $i$.

That is, if we consider the buckets $[2^i,2^{i+1})$ for $i=0,1,\dots$ the probability mass in each bucket is bounded by a same parameter. Furthermore if possible, within each bucket the density function should look as uniform as possible.

The easiest way to construct one such distribution is of course to choose one of the first $\lceil 1/p\rceil$ buckets uniformly, then draw from an uniform distribution within that bucket. But I would like to know if one can be less aggressive and make the support to be $[0,\infty)$ while still have a finite mean.

I have considered Gamma distribution but it seems $F(2x)-F(x)$ only starts decreasing when $x$ is on the order of the mean.

Comment: @RobertIsrael The exponential distribution is a special case of the Gamma distribution, so $x$ still needs to be roughly the mean for $F(2x)-F(x)$ to start decreasing. In fact you can add any offset $c$, and $F(c+2x)-F(c+x)$ will not start decreasing before $x$ is roughly the mean.

Comment: For any distribution, you'll always have $F(2x) - F(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0+$, so it can't start decreasing right away.

Comment: But since all you want is an upper bound, why does that matter?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I'd like the upper bound to be a parameter, and you are right that $F(2x)-F(x)$ cannot start decreasing immediately. I just realized I can push down the upper bound by replacing the $2$ by $1+\epsilon$ but that seems to create contention with other parts of my problem. I'll need to think more to be able to ask my question properly.